# VB.NET: DataGridViewImageCell - Image from Ressource?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have added a datagridview on a windows form with the name DataGridView1. The following code adds a row with 2 columns. I want to show an image in the 2nd column.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("TESTROW")
dt.Rows.Add("TESTCONTENT")
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

Dim colImage As New DataGridViewImageColumn
DataGridView1.Columns.Add(colImage)

For intI As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count
    Dim cellImage As New DataGridViewImageCell
    ' THE FOLLOWING LINE WORKS FINE!!!!
    cellImage.Value = Drawing.Image.FromFile("c:\foo\bar.gif")

    ' BUT WHY NOT THIS?
    ' cellImage.Value = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("ExistingRessource")
    ' OR THIS?
    ' cellImage.Value = CType(Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("ExistingRessource"), Image)

    cellImage.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom
    DataGridView1.Rows(intI).Cells(1) = cellImage
Next
```

It's working fine if I use "fromFile" with the path to the image and the 2nd column shows the gif picture inside the cell.

Unfortunately, my attempt to load an image from the ressource ("GetObject") fails, and the cell shows a page-symbol with a red cross on it.

I got all the images I need inside the ressource.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've added an image to the resources, then you can access it with my.resources.ResourceName where ResourceName seems to be "ExistingRessource" in your case

It's possible that your current attempts are failing because the resource isn't actually added properly, or you have got the spelling wrong on the name? Either way if you use my.resources you can see for certain that the resource is added properly.

```
cellImage.Value = My.Resources.ExistingRessource
```

Comment: Oh yes, the "My" was missing. Thank you, it's working fine now.